# Get-MsolSubscription user permissions

Tags: office365, azure-powershell

I am using the "MSOnline V1 PowerShell module for Azure Active Directory" to fetch subscription info for an O365 tenant.

A connection to the Azure Active Directory is initiated with the `Connect-MsolService` cmdlet. Afterward, `Get-MsolSubscription` is executed. This returns the data just fine. However, I couldn't find the documentation about permissions required to invoke the `Get-MsolSubscription` cmdlet.

Does the user that is fetching subscriptions has to be assigned to a specific role in O365?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a general user (without any admin role) with `Connect-MsolService` and execute this cmdlet `Get-MsolSubscription` successfully.

So I don't think any role is required to invoke the `Get-MsolSubscription` cmdlet.